# java store objects that may be garbage collected

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In Java, I recall there is a way to store objects in a usable format that may be garbage collected.  It is some sort of loose reference.   If they get garbage collected there is a way to detect and reload.

I'm having a hard time finding this.  There is so much information about GC in general.  Anyone know the name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [WeakReference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking of [Weak References.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `*Reference` classes in [`java.lang.ref`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html). The `ReferenceQueue` class allows you to be notified when a reference is collected.

You might also find [FinalizableReference](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/FinalizableReference.html) from Google Guava useful.